# basemap set_bad() for Nan values

Tags: python, raster, matplotlib-basemap, contourf

I have tried to use numpy masked array and basemap module to plot raster data with no-data values. I defined a color map as cmap and then used cmap.set_bad(color='grey') to set no-data value to color gray. I then use contourf(...,cmap=cmap) to plot the raster, however, the no-data is still shown as white color.

I have been searching a lot of examples of "set_bad", it looks like it works fine for imshow() function. I wonder does anyone have any experience using contourf and set_bad to show the raster images with nodata values?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry. What do you mean? is the question unlcear?